# Sending an array to Micronaut Graphql for query from ReactJS

Tags: java, reactjs, graphql, micronaut, swr

I'm trying to send an array of strings from reactjs to micronaut, to test if the data is being successfully passed, I have something like this in the frontend:

```
const [filterName, setName] = useState(["test"]);
const age = 1;

const { data: people } = useSWR([`
     query ($name:[String], $age:Int){
        getName(name:$name, age:$age){ ... }`, filterName, age], (query, filterName, age) => fetcher(query, {filterName, age}))
```

My micronaut backend looks something like this:

```
@GraphQLQuery(name = "getName")
List<User> getName (@GraphQLArgument(name = "name") List<String> name,
                    @GraphQLArgument(name = "age") Integer age ){

    System.out.println("name: " + name.toString());
    System.out.println("age: " + age);
}
```

I can print the *age* but the *name* prints null. Am I doing something wrong? I've tried using ArrayList instead of List, still can't receive the name properly.I hope you can help. Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure about the reason, but for me, it looks like a problem with Micronauts.
Please check the below link for a better understanding : https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-graphql-in-kotlin-and-micronaut

Comment: I've checked that link before, it didn't really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the variables inside fetcher. It needed to match the api name declared in micronaut. It should've been like this:

```
const [filterName, setName] = useState(["test"]);
const age = 1;

const { data: people } = useSWR([`
     query ($name:[String], $age:Int){
        getName(name:$name, age:$age){ ... }`, filterName, age], (query, filterName, age) => fetcher(query, {name:filterName, age}))
```